# Stack Snippet works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: support, bug, stack-snippets, google-chrome

The snippet in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029065/refactoring-jquery-show-hide/42029312#42029312) is not working in Chrome (version 55.0), although it works fine in Firefox (version 45.0)

I see the following error message:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at tb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:17863)
    at Jb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:21147)
    at n.fn.init.show (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:23399)
    at n.fn.init.n.fn.(anonymous function) [as show] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:30325)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://stacksnippets.net/js:27:37)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:6404)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:3179)
```

Comment: It works if i change ` <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to ` <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` Maybe some bug specific in jQuery 2.1.1?

Comment: But it works in firefox with the same jQuery version..

Comment: No-repro here in chrome v55 on windows 7.

Comment: I can repro different behaviors in Firefox 50 vs Chrome 55 in Win7.

Comment: On Win10x64: Works in Firefox 51.0.1 and FF54.0a1 (I didn't bother testing other versions of FF), NOT working in Chrome 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit), Edge 38.14393.0.0, IE11.576.14393.0, and Opera 42.0.2393.517.

Comment: Works for me with Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro. @Makyen Could you also try Chrome 56?

Comment: @tambre, Fails for me on Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit). Win 10 Pro x64.

Comment: Yes please add `allow-same-origin` param in stacksnippets `sandbox` attribute. Too many codes fail because of it. [Here is a fiddle where I can repro OP's issue](https://jsfiddle.net/v8pco3r0/), and [here is one where it has been fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/v8pco3r0/1) thanks to this param. The security shouldn't be compromised, since snippets are loaded from a different origin anyway (stacksnippets.net). The only concern I can think of would be that one could save / get a localStorage item across different snippets. (Ps: I can repro on chrome 56 and 58 on osX)